# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't start after install some developing softwre

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. After that, I installed some software like github, git, sublime text, netbeans, eclipse and I changed the memory swap from 60 to 10. I turned off my computer and in the morning when I turn on the laptop, there is only the Ubuntu logo and doesn't show anything else, I am new to Linux and I don't know how to fix this, please help.

Comment: What does "*I changed the memory swap from 60 to 10*" mean? Perhaps you should list the commands that you actually used (in order, of course).

Comment: Probably `swappiness`.

Comment: 1: wait longer. 2: check other connected monitors